# Unable to Install nfs-utils package in redhat/ubi8-micro:8.6 docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel, nfs, rhel8

I'm customizing a Dockerfile for an application which is using `redhat/ubi8-micro:8.6` as the base image and I want to install `nfs-utils` package on top of that.

I enabled all the repos that was available within the image under `/etc/yum.repos.d/ubi.repo`.

```
[ubi-8-baseos-rpms]
[ubi-8-baseos-debug-rpms]
[ubi-8-baseos-source]
[ubi-8-appstream-rpms]
[ubi-8-appstream-debug-rpms]
[ubi-8-appstream-source]
```

I can install other packages using `microdnf` package manger which is available within the image, but the `nfs-utils` package is not available.

I tried below ways to install it.

1. A multi-stage docker build to install `nfs-utils` package and tried copying over all the files but it didn't work, As some dependencies and libraries were missing
2. Downloaded the `nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.68.el7.x86_64.rpm` rpm package directly from internet and tried installing with `rpm -ivh nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.68.el7.x86_64.rpm` but it fails to install as it expects other dependencies to installed before installing it.

Is there a simple way to install the `nfs-utils` package inside `redhat/ubi8-micro:8.6` docker image?

Comment: The `microdnf` command doesn't appear to be available in that image.

Comment: You could try installing the `nfs-utils` package available from the [Centos 8-stream repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/).

Comment: Thank you @larsks I was able to install the `nfs-utils` package with centos-8 repository that you provided with below commands.


# First I installed yum
`RUN microdnf install -y yum` 

# Than installed `nfs-utils` with below command
`RUN yum --nogpgcheck --repofrompath=centos,http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/ install -y nfs-utils`